# Proving the Mode of Negative Binomial

Tags: probability, negative-binomial

I refer to the answer by BruceET mentioned here: [Finding the mode of the negative binomial distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302106/finding-the-mode-of-the-negative-binomial-distribution)

It is mentioned that the mode of negative binomial distribution can be found by:
t = 1 + ((r-1)/p)
where t is some number, r is the number of successes and p is the probability of success
If t is an integer, there will be 2 modes at t and t-1
If t is not an integer, the integer part of t is the mode. E.g. '3' is the integer part of 3.5

This is what I have worked on so far:
((r-1)/p) is the expected number of attempts to achieve all required successes excluding the final success
The expected number of attempts + the definite final success = the total number of expected attempts.The total number of expected attempts is the mode.

Why could there be two modes of t-1 and t?

P(X=x) = ((x-1) choose (r-1))(p^r)(q^(x-r))

((t-2)choose(r-1))(p^r)(q^(t-r-1)) = ((t-1)choose(r-1))(p^r)(q^(t-r))

((t-2)choose(r-1))(q^-1) = ((t-1)choose(r-1))

((t-2)(t-3)...(t-r))/(r-1)! x (q^-1) = ((t-1)(t-2)...(t-r+1))/(r-1)!

(t-r)/q = t-1 [I am stuck here]

Furthermore, I don't know why if t is not an integer, the integer part of t is the mode.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $\dfrac{t-r}{q}=t-1$ then you also have $t-r=qt-q$ and thus $t=\dfrac{r-q}{1-q}= 1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$.

This says that

- if $x < 1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ then $\mathbb{P}(X=x) < \mathbb{P}(X=x-1)$
- if $x = 1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ then $\mathbb{P}(X=x) = \mathbb{P}(X=x-1)$
- if $x > 1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ then $\mathbb{P}(X=x) < \mathbb{P}(X=x-1)$

So with $1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ integer then it and  $\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ have the same highest probabilities and are the modes

while if $1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$ is not an integer then the mode is the integer immediately below it

Comment: If you have t−rq=t−1

why is this so?

Comment: You do not have $t-rq=t-1$.  Taking  $\dfrac{t-r}{q}=t-1$, you can multiply both sides by $q$ to give $t-r=qt-q$ which you can rearrange to $t-qt=r-q$ or $(1-q)t=r-q$ and then dividing both sides by $(1-q)=p$ to give $t=\dfrac{r-q}{1-q}=\dfrac{1-q +r-1}{1-q}=\dfrac{p +r-1}{p} = 1+\dfrac{r-1}{p}$